# CSS shadow as image

Tags: css

I have these 3 boxes

[image]

Which are constructed in the following way:

```
    <ul class="home_boxs">
        <li class="home_box light_blue">
        <div class="news clearfix"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="home_box blue">
        <div class="news clearfix"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="home_box dark_blue">
        <div class="news clearfix"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What I am looking to do now is to add a small shadow image (custom png) underneath each box. What would be the best way to have this achieved? Some advise would be very much appreciated.

See sample:

[image]

Comment: See this:http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/ and how do http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
.home_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; /* to change with your size */
    height: 100px;
    /* To add more styling according to your needs */
}
.home_box:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(//placehold.it/150x10); /* placeholder */
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

or, if you don't wanna use images:

```
.home_box:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #999999;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: -20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999999;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/tfe3E/) with image - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/spL23/) without image